# Is there a way to filter out hidden names in XSSFWorkbook.allNames?

Tags: apache-poi

I am interested in getting a list of user-defined named ranges (as it appears in Excel application UI) using Apache POI.

I can filter out the built-ins using the static properties of [XSSFName](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFName.html), but there might be others that are set by plugins etc. Below is a (shortened) real-world example with hidden names:

```
<definedName name="user_named_range">...</definedName>
<definedName name="_xlnm._FilterDatabase" hidden="1">...</definedName>
<definedName name="CIQWBGuid" hidden="1">...</definedName>
<definedName name="ExactAddinConnection" hidden="1">...</definedName>
```

`workbook.allNames` returns all of them. How can I recognise `user_named_range` as user-defined and skip all others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until now `XSSFName` lacks access to the `hidden` attribute of the underlying `CTDefinedName`. So, if needed, one would need to get that underlying `CTDefinedName`. Unfortunately the method `getCTName` has protected access only. But fortunately there is `java.lang.reflect`.

Example:

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDefinedName;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class ReadExcelXSSFNameDetails {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./inputFile.xlsm"));

  for (XSSFName name : workbook.getAllNames()) {
   String nameName = name.getNameName();

   Method getCTName = XSSFName.class.getDeclaredMethod("getCTName");
   getCTName.setAccessible(true);
   CTDefinedName ctName = (CTDefinedName)getCTName.invoke(name);
   //System.out.println(ctName);

   boolean isHidden = ctName.getHidden();
   System.out.println("Found name " + nameName + ". Is this name hidden? " + isHidden);

  }

  workbook.close();

 }

}
```

Now you can detect whether a stored name has hidden attribute set.

Comment: Oddly this looks like something that HSSF has more support for than XSSF - https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/4fd05fac12a32de2e6312e93c463277a40b6ff20/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/NameRecord.java#L243

Comment: @Gagravarr: For me it looks like the same kind of support in `HSSF` and `XSSF`. `HSSFName` also lacks access to the `hidden` property while underlying `NameRecord` has that. Same as the `XSSFName` lacks access to the `hidden` property while underlying `CTDefinedName` has that.  Also `SS` interface  [Name](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Name.html) does not require that access.

Comment: [Coming to an Apache POI release near you soon](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Name.java#L167) - `Name.isHidden()` :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, using the reflection. Will do for now. And looking forward to `isHidden` in the next release, @Gagravarr!